# Augmenting array via for loop only keeps last object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Given my **core data** is such as :

```
var data = [
    { name: "Student01", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ] },
    { name: "Student02", type: "given", grades: [ 11,6,15, 12 ] },
    { name: "Student03", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ]  },
    { name: "Student04", type: "given", grades: [ 12,8,13, 12 ] }
];
```

Given a **template object** which I should respect :

```
var template = {
  text: "Hello guys !",
  side: "negative",
  name: "Some student",
  x: [ 12.65, 17.92, 16.45 ],
  orientation: "h"
};
```

I then build up an **`augmentedData` via for loop** :

```
var augmentedData = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var trace = template, 
         student = data[i];
    trace.text = "Step "+i;
    trace.name = student.name;
    trace.x    = student.grades;
    console.log(student, student.type)
    trace.side = student.type == "given"?"negative":"positive";
    console.log(vizGrades[i].type, trace, trace.side)
    augmentedData.push(trace);
}
```

My final augmented data is composed of 4 times the last object, itself augmented :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(augmentedData));
```

returns:

```
[
  {"text":"Step 3","side":"negative","name":"Student04","x":[12,8,13,12],"orientation":"h"},
  {"text":"Step 3","side":"negative","name":"Student04","x":[12,8,13,12],"orientation":"h"},
  {"text":"Step 3","side":"negative","name":"Student04","x":[12,8,13,12],"orientation":"h"},
  {"text":"Step 3","side":"negative","name":"Student04","x":[12,8,13,12],"orientation":"h"}
];
```

**What is going wrong ? How to fix it ?**

**EDIT: Expected output :**

```
[
  {"text":"Step 0","side":"positive","name":"Student01","x":[12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15],"orientation":"h"},
  {"text":"Step 1","side":"negative","name":"Student02","x":[11,6,15, 12],"orientation":"h"},
  {"text":"Step 2","side":"positive","name":"Student03","x":[12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15],"orientation":"h"},
  {"text":"Step 3","side":"negative","name":"Student04","x":[12,8,13,12],"orientation":"h"}
];
```

Comment: What is your expected outpu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we are referencing the same object each iteration and creating an array of the same object. In order to prevent this we will need to copy the contents of the `template` object into the `trace` object.

You can accomplish this with a shallow copy. There are several ways to make a shallow copy in Javascript I used the spread operator (`var trace = {...template}`) to copy a new template into trace.

```js
var data = [
    { name: "Student01", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ] },
    { name: "Student02", type: "given", grades: [ 11,6,15, 12 ] },
    { name: "Student03", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ]  },
    { name: "Student04", type: "given", grades: [ 12,8,13, 12 ] }
];

var template = {
  text: "Hello guys !",
  side: "negative",
  name: "Some student",
  x: [ 12.65, 17.92, 16.45 ],
  orientation: "h"
};

var augmentedData = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var trace = {...template}, 
         student = data[i];
    trace.text = "Step "+i;
    trace.name = student.name;
    trace.x    = student.grades;
    trace.side = student.type == "given"?"negative":"positive";

    augmentedData.push(trace);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(augmentedData));
```

Comment: Hey, are there some notable browser support issue with this `{...}` approach ?

Comment: Per usual IE will give you a hard time. Here is MDN's browser break down: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

> What is going wrong ? How to fix it ?

By writing `var trace = template` you're declaring only a **reference** to `template` object.  As you modify the `trace` object, `template` will be modified also.

You need a deep copy for your `template` object. For this, you can use `Object.assign` method.

Working example.

```js
var data = [
    { name: "Student01", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ] },
    { name: "Student02", type: "given", grades: [ 11,6,15, 12 ] },
    { name: "Student03", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ]  },
    { name: "Student04", type: "given", grades: [ 12,8,13, 12 ] }
];

var template = {
  text: "Hello guys !",
  side: "negative",
  name: "Some student",
  x: [ 12.65, 17.92, 16.45 ],
  orientation: "h"
};

var augmentedData = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    var trace = Object.assign({}, template), 
    student = data[i];
    trace.text = "Step "+i;
    trace.name = student.name;
    trace.x    = student.grades;
    console.log(student, student.type)
    trace.side = student.type == "given"?"negative":"positive";
    augmentedData.push(trace);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(augmentedData));
```

You can use `map` method by passing a callback function in order to write a more clean and easy solution for your requirement.

Also, create an **object constructor** called template.

```js
var data = [
    { name: "Student01", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ] },
    { name: "Student02", type: "given", grades: [ 11,6,15, 12 ] },
    { name: "Student03", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ]  },
    { name: "Student04", type: "given", grades: [ 12,8,13, 12 ] }
];
function template(text, side, name, x) {
    this.text = text;
    this.side = side;
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.orientation = "h";
}

const augmentedData = data.map((student, i) => 
   new template(`Step ${i}`, student.name, student.grades, student.type === "given" ? "negative" : "positive")
);
console.log(augmentedData);
```

Comment: I suspected something is this direction... any recommendation ?

Comment: @HugoLOPEZ, just use `Object.assign` method like in my updated answer.

Comment: @HugoLOPEZ, I updated my answer with a more clean and easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

The line `trace = template` only passes a reference to trace from template so you are working with the same object all the way in the loop.

Try

```
var template = function() {
  return {
    text: "Hello guys !",
    side: "negative",
    name: "Some student",
    x: [ 12.65, 17.92, 16.45 ],
    orientation: "h"
  };
}
```

So `trace` becomes a new object every time using `trace = template();`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29wkq5gb/1/)

Comment: Pretty Slick : )

Answer (score 1):

When you do `var trace = template` you are just creating a new variable containing a reference to the *same* object.

Instead of creating the object named `template`, you should create a new object each time like so:

```js
var data = [
    { name: "Student01", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ] },
    { name: "Student02", type: "given", grades: [ 11,6,15, 12 ] },
    { name: "Student03", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ]  },
    { name: "Student04", type: "given", grades: [ 12,8,13, 12 ] }
];

var augmentedData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var student = data[i];

    var trace = {
      text: "Step " + i,
      side: student.type == "given" ? "negative" : "positive",
      name: student.name,
      x: student.grades,
      orientation: "h"
    };

    augmentedData.push(trace);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(augmentedData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `trace` variable is a *reference* to the `template` object, so whenever you change some property of `trace`, it will also change in the referenced object (`template`).

One way of avoiding this problem is to rewrite your code as a `map` operation. This is the perfect use-case for map.

It would look something like this:

```js
const data = [
    { name: "Student01", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ] },
    { name: "Student02", type: "given", grades: [ 11,6,15, 12 ] },
    { name: "Student03", type: "received", grades: [ 12,12, 17, 17, 14.5, 10, 16, 15.5, 15.5, 15 ]  },
    { name: "Student04", type: "given", grades: [ 12,8,13, 12 ] }
];

const augmentedData = data.map((student, i) => ({
  text: `Step ${i}`,
  name: student.name,
  x: student.grades,
  side: student.type === "given" ? "negative" : "positive",
}));

console.log(augmentedData);
```